# Best tool to create notches (custom pull-up bar)

Tags: wood, power-tools, tool-selection

I would like to create a custom (hallway) pull-up bar. Example:

[image]

**Question**

I'm wondering what the best tool would be to create the notches?

I'm thinking of either a Hole Saw or a Jigsaw? Or do I need both?

Thanks in advance,

Sebastian

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically you could do this entirely using a jigsaw, but generally notches of this type are created by drilling a hole and then sawing in from the edge to meet the hole.

In case it's not obvious the first step is to accurately mark out your notches and the positions of your mounting screws.

Assuming you're not using a jigsaw for the whole operation, the drilling can be done using various types of bit — the most common choices, in no particular order, would be flat bits (AKA spade bits), Forstner bits or a hole saw.

The sawing can be done with any suitable hand saw, or using a jigsaw.

**Note:** both the drilling and sawing operations may tend to chip out wood from the exit side. There are ways to minimise this but you can instead plan ahead to have that face the one that mounts against the wall or door frame where it won't be seen.

You'll probably also want to have some sandpaper, or a couple of files, to clean up and smooth edges

Comment: Thanks! That's really nice advice I can use.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the diameter of the bar, you could use a router to directly route the notches. Easy for upto 16mm, dont know how readily available larger diameters are. For larger diameters you could also create a template and use a templating bit.

Afterwards, like Graphus said, sandpaper to clean up.

Comment: 16mm wouldn't be nearly beefy enough for a wooden chinning bar — 30mm is about the minimum diameter you want to go (even for kids). And 38 to over 40mm would not be uncommon. Steel ones mimic these dimensions, not necessarily because it's needed for strength but for comfort.